# Jaeger traces out of order

Tags: javascript, java, microservices, jaeger, opentracing

I have a front-end application (component A) that makes a request to a Java back-end application (component B).

Both components are configured to export trace information to my jaegertracing/all-in-one:1.37 deployment.

The headers from component A are propagating correctly to component B, and I can see the traces being nested, but they are out of order.[image]
[image]

I printed the start and end time for both component A and B, it looks like timestamp from component B is *earlier* than of component A. Has anyone run into this issue before?

The way I print the epoch time for both services are:

**Java**
System.currentTimeMillis();

**JavaScript**
new Date().getTime()

Answer (score 1):

Jaeger has a solution to address the possibility of clock skew between the many host machines part of the traces: https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.21/deployment/#clock-skew-adjustment

It is most likely the case that one of the host machines have a clock skew which causes the tracing to be out of order.